# Problemas para compilar en R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando compilar en html, pero me salta el siguiente error:

> Error in eval (expr, envir, enclos) : objeto 'modelo_de_madurez_bbdd' no encontrado
> Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

El código es:

```
#'Se analizará la expectativa de rendimiento, viendo los niveles
#porcentuales a nivel país de la satisfacción del usuario a nivel nacional
#en los servicios de salud

#'Instalar paquete Tidyverse

install.packages("tidyverse",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

#'renombrar base de datos, con respecto a la satisfacción del usuario relacionado
#'a las expectativas de esfuerzo.

Madurez <- modelo_de_madurez_bbdd


#'Seleccionar variable "Satisfacción de clientes"

Satisf <- Madurez[,c(1,21)]

#'Cambiar nombres columnas para trabajarlas con mas facilidad

colnames(Satisf) <- c('nombre_institución','Satisf_Clientes')

#'Seleccionar solo filas que empiecen con "Servicio de Salud"

Satisf2 <- filter(Satisf, grepl('Servicio de Salud', nombre_institución))
#'Ordenar datos por valor de Satisfacción de Clientes

arrange(Satisf2, Satisf_Clientes)

#'Limpieza de datos
#'Transformación de valores numericos a palabras

Satisf2$Satisf_Clientes <- factor(Satisf2$Satisf_Clientes,
                                  levels = c(1,2,3,4),
                                  labels = c("Nota 1", "Nota 2", "Nota 3", "Nota 4"))

#'Creación de nueva tabla con cantidades de veces que se repite una nota

Notas_Salud <- summary(Satisf2$Satisf_Clientes)

tabla_salud <- data.frame(Notas_Salud)

#'utilización de matutate para generar una nueva tabla con valores porcentuales

tabla_saludporcentaje = 
  mutate(tabla_salud, nota_pct = (Notas_Salud * 100 / sum(Notas_Salud)))
```

Comment: ¿De dónde viene `modelo_de_madurez_bbdd`?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que en el "environment" de R no está cargada la variable `modelo_de_madurez_bbdd` y por eso no la encuentra.

Cuando compilas a HTML, R no lee tu "environment actual" (las variables que ya tienes cargadas) sino que debes cargar todo dentro del archivo que estas compilando porque solo lee el "environment" que se va creando a medida que corre el programa .R. Parece raro pero eso hace que tu archivo sea completamente reproducible.

La solución es cargar esa variable en el mismo archivo .R que estas trantando de compilar a HTML.

(además no hace falta que instales el paquete tidyverse cada vez que corres el archivo, basta con que quites la línea `install.packages("tidyverse",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`y agregues `library(tidyverse)` y tu archivo va a correr mucho más rápido)

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió bastante

Comment: Si te sirvió y ayudó a resolver el problema podes dar como solucionada la pregunta o votarla positivo? Eso me ayudaría a mí, además te sumergis un poco más en como funciona StackOverflow! Acá ves como hacerlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers